# Coming Back to Python after Several Years. Unsure of best practices for reading/transforming pandas dataframes/arrays

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to read two csv files with corresponding information, and create a new array with values from both files.

The first csv file has many columns, but I am interested in: Product Names, Inventory Quanity, and ASIN columns. The second csv also has multiple columns, but I am interested in the ASIN and Stock columns.

I would like to iterate over the ASIN values of the first csv file (here loaded into dataFeedNames), and find the corresponding ASIN in the second csv file (here loaded into dataFeedInventory).

After I find the corresponding ASIN in dataFeedInventory, I would like to retrieve the corresponding row value in dataFeedInventory under the column 'Stocks'.

In the new array, I would load the Inventory Quantity, ASIN, and Product Name columns from dataFeedNames, as well as a new column, holding the corresponding value of 'Stocks' from dataFeedInventory.

The  thing is I vaguely remember that you're not actually supposed to iterate over a dataframe like this. And I am unsure about whether I should vectorize the columns or not.

Any code, suggestions, or youtube video recommendations on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import numpy as np

os.chdir('/someDirectory')

dataFeedNames = pd.read_csv('productNamesAndSalesVelocity.csv', sep = ',')
dataFeedInventory = pd.read_csv('inventoryPerformance.csv')

selectedColumnsNames = dataFeedNames [['ASIN','Product Name','Invetory Quantity']]
selectedColumnsInv = dataFeedInventory [['ASIN','Stocks']]

arrayNames = selectedColumnsNames.to_numpy()

##lookup ASIN in arrayNames
##find arrayNames(ASIN) in selectedColumnsInv
##return the corresponding Stocks number
##make a new column in arrayNames with the corresponding stock number, in the row with the corresponding ASIN
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When asking for help always create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In this case you should provide a sample of both DataFrames and the expected output inside a code block. A good way is to share the outputs of `print(df.to_dict())` along with `print(df)`, where `df` are your DataFrames.  It's much easier to understand what you want, instead of just describing your data in words.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. I'll have to do that next time.

Comment: You're welcome! Does my answer solve your issue? If it does, please mark it as accepted, or any answer that you prefer. If not, I can try to help you understand why.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want a left merge of both DataFrames on the "ASIN" column. That can be achieved using [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import numpy as np

os.chdir('/someDirectory')

dataFeedNames = pd.read_csv('productNamesAndSalesVelocity.csv', sep = ',')
dataFeedInventory = pd.read_csv('inventoryPerformance.csv')

selectedColumnsNames = dataFeedNames [['ASIN','Product Name','Invetory Quantity']]
selectedColumnsInv = dataFeedInventory [['ASIN','Stocks']]

merged = selectedColumnsNames.merge(selectedColumnsInv, how='left', on='ASIN')
print(merged)
```